# WPF ContentControl content set in DataTemplate trigger randomly resets to default content

Tags: wpf, datatemplate, datatrigger, contentcontrol

I'm having an issue with the content of a ContentControl whose content was set using DataTriggers randomly resetting the content to the default content specified in the DataTemplate.

The scenario is that I have a bunch of devices (sensors) out on the network that I need to check status on, among other things. Depending on what state the sensor is in I may want to show a colored circle (green, red or yellow), or an image. For example if the sensor is in use by someone I want to show an image representing a user. If the sensor is available for connection I want to show a green ellipse, etc.

I'm currently using a WPF DataGrid to display a list of sensors and their status, though I get the same erroneous behavior with a ListBox and ListView (haven't tried plain ItemsControl). FYI, sensors come and go asynchronously.

What you'll see if you run the sample code is that initially items with a connection state of CONNECTED will first display with the desired image. As rows get added to the grid the image randomly disappears and is replace with the default content specified in the DataTemplate. This problem only occurs when there is an image in the content. The other states work just fine.

Below is all the code (xaml, viewmodel, model) I think you'll need to see the behavior. Sorry for the amount of code posted below. I've tried to pair it down as much as possible to illustrate the issue. Hopefully the problem is obvious by looking at the XAML. The remaining source code will help you get it up and running more quickly if you so choose.

Here's the Window XAML:

```
<Window x:Class="StackOverflowGridIssue.MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:model="clr-namespace:StackOverflowGridIssue.Model"
    xmlns:shape="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/2010/drawing" 
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
    mc:Ignorable="d" Width="500"
    Title="MainWindow" >
  <Grid>
    <DataGrid Name="_SensorsDataGrid" ItemsSource="{Binding Sensors}" 
          AutoGenerateColumns="False" HeadersVisibility="Column"  >
      <DataGrid.Columns>

        <!-- Status -->
        <DataGridTemplateColumn Header="Status" MinWidth="50" 
                                Width="SizeToHeader" IsReadOnly="True">
          <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
              <ContentControl x:Name="myContent" Background="LimeGreen" 
                              Width="25" Height="25">
                <ContentControl.ToolTip>
                  <TextBlock Text="{Binding ConnectionState, Mode=OneWay}" 
                             Foreground="Black" />
                </ContentControl.ToolTip>
                <ContentControl.Style>
                  <Style TargetType="{x:Type ContentControl}" BasedOn="{x:Null}" >
                    <Setter Property="Template">
                      <Setter.Value>
                        <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type ContentControl}">
                          <Grid>
                            <Ellipse Height="10" Width="10"
                                 Fill="{TemplateBinding Background}" 
                                 Stroke="{TemplateBinding Background}" />
                            <ContentPresenter />
                          </Grid>
                        </ControlTemplate>
                      </Setter.Value>
                    </Setter>
                  </Style>
                </ContentControl.Style>
              </ContentControl>

              <DataTemplate.Triggers>
                <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding ConnectionState, Mode=OneWay}" 
                       Value="{x:Static model:ConnectionStateType.NOT_FOUND}">
                  <Setter TargetName="myContent" Property="Background" Value="Red" />
                </DataTrigger>

                <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding ConnectionState, Mode=OneWay}" 
                       Value="{x:Static model:ConnectionStateType.AVAILABLE}">
                  <Setter TargetName="myContent" Property="Background" 
                      Value="GREEN" />
                </DataTrigger>

                <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding ConnectionState, Mode=OneWay}" 
                       Value="{x:Static model:ConnectionStateType.CONNECTED}">
                  <Setter TargetName="myContent" Property="Content">
                    <Setter.Value>
                      <Image Source="Images/User.png" />
                    </Setter.Value>
                  </Setter>
                </DataTrigger>

              </DataTemplate.Triggers>
            </DataTemplate>
          </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
        </DataGridTemplateColumn>


        <!-- DEBUG Connection State -->
        <DataGridTextColumn Header="DEBUG" 
                  Binding="{Binding ConnectionState}" Width="SizeToCells" />

        <!-- Sensor Name -->
        <DataGridTextColumn Header="Sensor Name" 
                  Binding="{Binding Name}" Width="SizeToCells" />

        <!-- IPAddress -->
        <DataGridTextColumn Header="IP Address" 
                            Binding="{Binding IPAddress}" Width="SizeToCells" />
      </DataGrid.Columns>
    </DataGrid>
  </Grid>
</Window>
```

Here's the App.xaml.cs where I bootstrap everything and simulate sensors being discovered asynchronously (fyi, the same issue occurs if I load them serially, it's just easier to see when the sensors are loaded slowly one at a time:

```
  /// <summary>
  /// Interaction logic for App.xaml
  /// </summary>
  public partial class App : Application
  {
    public const int NUM_SENSORS = 100;
    Random _connectionStateGenerator = new Random();
    ConnectionStateType _connectionState = ConnectionStateType.AVAILABLE;

    SensorViewModel viewModel;

    Timer _timer = new Timer(300);
    int _index = 1;
    protected override void OnStartup(StartupEventArgs e)
    {
      base.OnStartup(e);

      // Get a handle to the main view (MainWindow)
      Window window = new MainWindow();

      viewModel = new SensorViewModel();

      //Loads sensors synchronously (same issue)
      //AddSensors(viewModel.Sensors);

      window.DataContext = viewModel;

      window.Show();

      //Simulate async sensor discovery (more real world example)
      _timer.Enabled = false;
      _timer.AutoReset = true;
      _timer.Elapsed += (s, args) =>
        {
          Dispatcher.InvokeAsync(new Action( () =>
            {
              viewModel.Sensors.Add(
                new Sensor("Sensor" + _index, "192.168.1." + _index, 
                        (ConnectionStateType)_connectionStateGenerator.Next(0, 3)));

              if (_index++ > NUM_SENSORS)
                _timer.Enabled = false;
            }));
        };
      _timer.Enabled = true;
    }


    //Helper for loading synchronously rather than asynchronously
    private void AddSensors(ObservableCollection<Model.Sensor> sensors)
    {
      for (int i = 0; i < NUM_SENSORS; i++)
      {
        _connectionState = (ConnectionStateType)_connectionStateGenerator
          .Next(0, 5);
        sensors.Add(
          new Sensor("Sensor" + i, "192.168.1." + i, _connectionState));
      }
    }
  }
```

Here's the model code representing a sensor:

```
  public enum ConnectionStateType
  {
    NOT_FOUND,
    AVAILABLE,
    CONNECTED,
  }

  public class Sensor : INotifyPropertyChanged
  {

    string _name = "Unknown";
    string _IPAddress;
    ConnectionStateType _connectionState = ConnectionStateType.AVAILABLE;

    public Sensor(string name, string IPAddress, ConnectionStateType connectionState)
    {
      _name = name;
      _IPAddress = IPAddress;
      _connectionState = connectionState;
    }

    public ConnectionStateType ConnectionState
    {
      get { return _connectionState; }

      set
      {
        if (value == _connectionState) return;
        _connectionState = value;
        NotifyPropertyChanged("ConnectionState");
      }
    }

    public string Name
    {
      get { return _name; }

      set
      {
        if (value == _name) return;
        _name = value;
        NotifyPropertyChanged("Name");
      }
    }

    public string IPAddress
    {
      get { return _IPAddress; }

      set
      {
        if (value == _IPAddress) return;
        _IPAddress = value;
        NotifyPropertyChanged("IPAddress");
      }
    }


    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    public void NotifyPropertyChanged(string property)
    {
      var handler = PropertyChanged;
      if(handler != null)
        handler(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(property));
    }
  }
```

Here's the View Model:

```
  public class SensorViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
  {
    ObservableCollection<Sensor> _sensors = new ObservableCollection<Sensor>();

    public ObservableCollection<Sensor> Sensors
    {
      get { return _sensors; }
      private set
      {
        if (value == _sensors) return;
        _sensors = value;
        NotifyPropertyChanged("Sensors");
      }
    }

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    public void NotifyPropertyChanged(string property)
    {
      var handler = PropertyChanged;
      if(handler != null)
        handler(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(property));
    }
  }
```

Thanks for your help.

Comment: Appears the problem is with my XAML. From what I can tell XAML doesn't like that I'm setting the default content to text, then trying to inject and image via a trigger. I've solved the problem using separate templates, one for text, and another for the image. I will post as answer shortly.

Answer (score 0):

The solution ended up being to have the trigger swap out the entire template rather than trying to set the Content area in the template.

Here is a cleaner piece XAML with template resources defined and a DataGrid that uses those resources:

```
<UserControl x:Class="StackOverflowGridIssue.SensorGrid"
             xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
             xmlns:model="clr-namespace:StackOverflowGridIssue.Model"
             xmlns:shape="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/2010/drawing" 
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
             xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
             xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
             mc:Ignorable="d" d:DesignHeight="300" d:DesignWidth="300">

  <UserControl.Resources>
    <ControlTemplate x:Key="DefaultConnectionStateTemplate" 
                     TargetType="{x:Type ContentControl}">
      <Grid>
        <Ellipse Height="10" Width="10"
                 Fill="{TemplateBinding Background}" 
                 Stroke="{TemplateBinding Background}" />
        <ContentPresenter HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center" />
      </Grid>
    </ControlTemplate>

    <ControlTemplate x:Key="ConnectedTemplate" 
                     TargetType="{x:Type ContentControl}" x:Shared="false">
      <Grid>
        <Image Source="Images/User.png" Height="25" Width="25"/>
        <ContentPresenter HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center" />
      </Grid>
    </ControlTemplate>

    <DataTemplate x:Key="SensorConnectionStateTemplate">
      <ContentControl x:Name="myContent">
        <ContentControl.ToolTip>
          <TextBlock Text="{Binding ConnectionState, Mode=OneWay}" />
        </ContentControl.ToolTip>
        <ContentControl.Style>
          <Style TargetType="{x:Type ContentControl}" BasedOn="{x:Null}" >
            <Setter Property="Template" 
                    Value="{StaticResource DefaultConnectionStateTemplate}" />
          </Style>
        </ContentControl.Style>
      </ContentControl>

      <DataTemplate.Triggers>
        <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding ConnectionState, Mode=OneWay}" 
                     Value="{x:Static model:ConnectionStateType.NOT_FOUND}">
          <Setter TargetName="myContent" Property="Background" Value="Red" />
          <Setter TargetName="myContent" Property="Content" Value="Not Found" />
        </DataTrigger>

        <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding ConnectionState, Mode=OneWay}" 
                     Value="{x:Static model:ConnectionStateType.AVAILABLE}">
          <Setter TargetName="myContent" Property="Background" Value="GREEN" />
          <Setter TargetName="myContent" Property="Content" Value="Available" />
        </DataTrigger>

        <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding ConnectionState, Mode=OneWay}" 
                     Value="{x:Static model:ConnectionStateType.CONNECTED}">
          <Setter TargetName="myContent" Property="Template" 
                  Value="{StaticResource ConnectedTemplate}" />
          <Setter TargetName="myContent" Property="Content" Value="Connected" />
        </DataTrigger>

      </DataTemplate.Triggers>
    </DataTemplate>

  </UserControl.Resources>

  <Grid>
    <DataGrid Name="_SensorsDataGrid" AutoGenerateColumns="False" 
              ItemsSource="{Binding Sensors}" 
              HeadersVisibility="Column"  >
      <DataGrid.Columns>

        <!-- Status -->
        <DataGridTemplateColumn Header="Status" MinWidth="50" 
                                Width="SizeToHeader" IsReadOnly="True" 
                                CellTemplate="{StaticResource SensorConnectionStateTemplate}" />

        <!-- DEBUG Connection State -->
        <DataGridTextColumn Header="DEBUG" 
                            Binding="{Binding ConnectionState}" Width="SizeToCells" />

        <!-- Sensor Name -->
        <DataGridTextColumn Header="Sensor Name" 
                            Binding="{Binding Name}" Width="SizeToCells" />

        <!-- IPAddress -->
        <DataGridTextColumn Header="IP Address"  Width="SizeToCells"
                            Binding="{Binding IPAddress}" />
      </DataGrid.Columns>
    </DataGrid>
  </Grid>
</UserControl>
```